# Is there a difference between traversing a list in python with range keyword and by use of other variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program where I add a '*' in front of every line of my string.

This is what I did:

```
text = "Lists of animals, Lists of aquarium life"

lines = text.split(',')

for l in lines:
    l = '* ' + l
print(lines)
```

This gives the output:

```
['Lists of animals', 'Lists of aquarium life']
```

But if I make a simple change where I use:

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = '* ' + lines[i]
print(lines)
```

This gives me the desired output that is:

```
['* Lists of animals', '* Lists of aquarium life']
```

Why is this happening? Can I make in-place changes to a list only when I traverse it through the range method?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `range(len(...))` is considered an anti-pattern in Python. If (and only if) you need the index, use `enumerate(...)` instead.

Comment: `l = '* ' + l` simply overwrites the variable l. while `lines[i] = '* ' + lines[i]` overwrites lines[i]

Comment: In the first instance youre changing `l` only, in the second youre changing `lines` specifically. You shouldnt change a list in place whilst looping through it. You could use list comprehension to return a new list with what you want. `linestar = ['*' + l for l in lines]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in code 1

```
text = "Lists of animals, Lists of aquarium life"
lines = text.split(',')
for l in lines:
    l = '* ' + l
print(lines)
```

a new string object `l` is being created ie `l = '* ' + l`, and that's all. it is created only and is not saved anywhere, not in the lines list. Because of this `lines` list is not updated and you are getting the same result.

To verify this, you can check the `id` of each element in the list.

```
text = "Lists of animals, Lists of aquarium life"
lines = text.split(',')

text = "Lists of animals, Lists of aquarium life"
lines = text.split(',')

print("checking id before modifictaion in the list")
for i in lines:
    print("text >  {},  id -> {}".format(i, id(i)))
    
for l in lines:
    print("line/text -> {}".format(i))
    print("before  modification id  - > {}".format(id(l)))
    l = '* ' + l
    print("after modification id -> {}".format(id(l)))
    
print("checking id after modifictaion in the list")
for i in lines:
    print("line/text -> {},  id -> {}".format(i, id(i)))
```

list object ids

```
checking id before modifictaion in the list
text >  Lists of animals,  id -> 140630273648640
text >   Lists of aquarium life,  id -> 140630273650240
line/text ->  Lists of aquarium life
before  modification id  - > 140630273648640
after modification id -> 140630273561344
line/text ->  Lists of aquarium life
before  modification id  - > 140630273650240
after modification id -> 140630273561344
checking id after modifictaion in the list
line/text -> Lists of animals,  id -> 140630273648640
line/text ->  Lists of aquarium life,  id -> 140630273650240
```

while in code2, the updated list object is saved back in the list itself, thus making the change that you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Because the way `for l in lines: l = '* ' + l` works is something like this:

```py
for i in range(len(lines)):
    l = lines[i]
    l = '* ' + l
```

So if you assign anything to `l`, it won't affect `lines[i]`.

If you don't want to use the `range` method, use **List comprehension** instead:

```py
lines = ['* ' + l for l in lines]
```

Comment: Thank you. It completely solved my doubt!

Answer (score 0):

In first case you are affecting only the variable l.

```
for l in lines:
    l = '* ' + l
print(l)
```

In the second case you are changing the list.

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = '* ' + lines[i]
print(lines)
```

Now the output would be similar

Answer (score 0):

Your "l" is in the loop just a normal variable.
If you wanna make changes directly in the list, you have to call it:

```
for l in lines:
    lines[l] = '* ' + l
    print(lines)
```

Otherwise the changes are just made to the variable "l".